# How to render a JSX element inside a task module in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm working on a Teams App development and I want to add custom JSX elements inside a task module. How can I achieve that?

Also, is it possible to add custom components inside an Adaptive card?

Answer (score 1):

Custom components are not supported in Adaptive Cards, but task modules can also be custom web applications, and you can build these any way you want (react with jsx, or otherwise).

The best place to start is in the docs, at the [Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules) doc. From there, in the table of contents, there are links to learning more about launching your task module from either a tab or a bot (you can have the same task module be launched from either/both).

Comment: Can you please share a document or a tutorial link for that?

Comment: Updated, hope that helps.